# Use AppleScript within Mac Excel VBA to generate UTF-8 file

Tags: vba, excel, applescript

I have the following code that generates an XML file using VBA script within Excel for Mac 2016. Unfortunately it appears that it is not possible to generate UTF-8 files from Mac Excel VBA. It was suggested to call AppleScript from within Excel VBA, I've never used AppleScript, any insight on how to convert the code below that is within Excel to call AppleScript to generate a UTF-8 file and then write to it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub createXMLFile()
Dim My_Path1 As String
My_Path1 = MacScript("return (path to desktop folder) as string")

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, cl As Range
Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("upload").Range("A2")
Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("upload").Range(rng1, rng1.End(xlDown))

Dim strPath As String
strPath = "cancel_reasons"
Dim fnum As Integer
fnum = FreeFile()

Open My_Path1 & Trim(strPath) & ".xml" For Output As #fnum

Print #fnum, "<?xml version=""1.0""?>"
Print #fnum, "<x:cancelShiftReasons xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation=""urn:cancelShiftReasons ./cancelshiftreasonmaster.xsd"" xmlns:x=""urn:cancelShiftReasons"">"

For Each cl In rng1
  Call write_xml_line_2(cl, fnum)
Next cl

Print #fnum, "</x:cancelShiftReasons>"

Close #fnum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In Applescript, you just need to specify as «class utf8» when you are writing data. Overall, steps in AS are very similar to your VBA steps.

Because the script runs out of Excel, I added a "try" bloc (similar to the "on error" of VBA) to check the number of rows in Excel document. if no document open, then the script stops with a message. I added many comments to make it clear.

```
set H1 to "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" -- to insert " in Applescript, you must escape it by adding \ before
set H2 to "<x:cancelShiftReasons xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation=\"urn:cancelShiftReasons ./cancelshiftreasonmaster.xsd\" xmlns:x=\"urn:cancelShiftReasons\">"
set H3 to "</x:cancelShiftReasons>"

set MyPath to (path to desktop folder) as string
set myFile to "cancel_reasons1.xml"

try -- try to count number of rows in the range 
    tell application "Microsoft Excel" to set NbRows to count of rows of used range of active sheet -- assume that no empty rows in middle
on error
    display dialog "Error : Impossible to count rows" -- may be no Excel document open,...
    return
end try

set fnum to open for access file (MyPath & myFile) with write permission
set eof of fnum to 0 --> empty file contents if already exists
write (H1 & return) to fnum as «class utf8»
write (H2 & return) to fnum as «class utf8»

repeat with I from 2 to (NbRows + 1) -- loop through cells starting from A2
    tell application "Microsoft Excel" to set Cl to value of range ("A" & I & ":A" & I) of active sheet
    write (Cl & return) to fnum as «class utf8» -- write value of the cell I
end repeat

write H3 to fnum as «class utf8» -- not sure if return is required at end of xml ?
close access funm
```

I have a doubt about xml file last row : not sure if return is required at the end. if needed, just add the return like in other "write" lines.